# res.redirect in API route NextJS gives a loop

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I have this code in my `/api/[verificationToken]` which is when accessed by the user, the verification token will be updated. For now, I am trying to check if the token exists in the database and corresponds to a registered email.

```
import prisma from "../../../lib/prisma";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const token = req.query;
  const findEmail = await prisma.user.findFirst({
    where: {
      token: token.verificationToken,
    },
  });
  if (findEmail) {
    console.log("email exists");
  } else {
    console.log("email doesn't exist");
    return res.redirect("/auth/login");
  }
 
}
```

The problem is, when I go to `http://localhost:3000/auth/api/nonexistenttoken`, `"email doesn't exist"` displays in a loop. I have also tried

```
res.writeHead(302, {
   Location: '/auth/login'
});
res.end();
```

But it still gives me the same loop. What I want to happen is that when the token doesn't exist (which also means the email also doesn't), it should redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: Assuming you're making a request to the API route from your client code, you should handle the page redirect after the request is made on the client-side.